# ¿Mi cumpleaños es el "uno" o "un" de agosto?

Tags: gramática, números

Do I use primero or *uno/un* in the following sentence?

> Mi cumpleaños es el ____ de agosto

I know that I can say "mi cumpleaños es el dieciséis de abril," but I don't know what to do when I want to say that my birthday is the *first* of something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We say:

> Mi cumpleaños es el **uno** <s>un</s> de agosto

And of course *primero* is also correct:

> Mi cumpleaños es el **primero** de agosto

---

In its entry on [**uno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b6hEWeB%7Cb6iKApr), RAE says:

> Apóc. un<sup>1</sup> ante s. m. sing. y, por lo general, inmediatamente antes de s. f. sing. que empieza por /a/ tónica en aceps. 1 y 2.

That is:

> Apócope un<sup>1</sup> ante sustantivo masculino singular y, por lo general, inmediatamente antes de sustantivo femenino singular que empieza por /a/ tónica en acepciones 1 y 2.

Where apócope is *Supresión de algún sonido al final de un vocablo, como en primer por primero*.

So: you would suppress the *o* and say *un* when *uno* occurs before a singular masculine noun (*Yo tengo un maletín lleno de dinero*) or before a singular feminine noun that starts with a stressed *a* (*Vi un águila volando*).

In fact the second entry on *uno* explicitly talks about the case you mention:

> 2. adj. primero (‖ que precede a los demás de su especie). U. pospuesto al s. Me voy de vacaciones el día uno. **Apl. a los días del mes**, u. t. c. s. m. El uno de noviembre.

Where *Apl.* means *Aplicado* and  *u. t. c. s. m.*, *usado también como sustantivo masculino*.

All in all, this is the same you find for the usage of *primero*, that's why it is equivalent in usage:

> [**primero, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UAztjAx)
>   1. adj. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: Que precede a las demás de su especie en orden, tiempo, lugar, situación, clase o jerarquía. U. t. c. s. **Apl. a los días del mes**, u. t. c. s. m. El primero de mayo.

Comment: Plz don't forget to mention that _primero_ de agosto used to be the rule (the first of each month being the only ordinal), [is still valid](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UAztjAx) and [still in use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22primero+de+agosto%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=u_sZWPVciZ3GBJuipOgM).

Comment: @Rafael good point. Edited to make it more clear.